# Dot used with entries in integer programming with cvxopt.glpk

Tags: python, glpk, cvxopt

```
from cvxopt import matrix
from cvxopt.glpk import ilp
c = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
A_ineq = [[-1., 0., 0., -1., -1., -1., -1.], [-1., -1., 0., 0., -1., -1., -1.], [-1., -1., -1., 0., 0., -1., -1.], [-1., -1., -1., -1., 0., 0., -1.], [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., 0., 0.], [0., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., 0.], [0., 0., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.]]
B_ineq = [-17., -13., -15., -19., -14., -16., -11.]
status, x = ilp(matrix(c), G = matrix(A_ineq).T, h = matrix(B_ineq), I = set(range(0,7)))
print(x)
print(status)
```

Why should we use '.' with entries of A_inq and B_ineq? It's something about 'd type'.

Comment: To signal that those are floating-point based types.

Comment: @ sascha I didn't expect it to be that easy! So why aren't the entries of the other matrices 'floatized'?

Comment: It's unclear if that matters at all. But this could be the case depending on some internal low-lvl wrappers (python <-> c-based types). But yeah, from a LP/MILP standpoint, c, A and B are all floating-point based. What types cvxopt where is hopefully documented or one needs to have a look.